# Discrete Lanczos Derivatives

Tags: c++, c++17, numerical-methods, signal-processing

I have a [PR](https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/173) implementing denoising discrete Lanczos derivatives, following [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1080/00207160.2012.666348). The following code works well, but *the design is a train wreck*, and I was hoping to get some advice to improve it.

But here's what it does: Give it some noisy data, and it will compute a reasonable derivative from it, so long as the SNR > 1:

[image: LIGO signal]

The orange time series shows the raw LIGO signal. The blue is the derivative of the LIGO signal computed with the (n,p) = (60, 4) discrete Lanczos derivative, and the gray is the standard finite difference formula, which is total garbage.

I will only post the code, but here are the [tests](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostorg/math/d76d49533ab0d917579a471f1d542c02612ed421/test/lanczos_smoothing_test.cpp) and [documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostorg/math/d76d49533ab0d917579a471f1d542c02612ed421/doc/differentiation/lanczos_smoothing.qbk).

```
#ifndef BOOST_MATH_DIFFERENTIATION_LANCZOS_SMOOTHING_HPP
#define BOOST_MATH_DIFFERENTIATION_LANCZOS_SMOOTHING_HPP
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>

namespace boost::math::differentiation {

namespace detail {
template <typename Real>
class discrete_legendre {
  public:
    explicit discrete_legendre(size_t n) : m_n{n}, m_r{2},
                                           m_x{std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN()},
                                           m_qrm2{std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN()},
                                           m_qrm1{std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN()},
                                           m_qrm2p{std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN()},
                                           m_qrm1p{std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN()},
                                           m_qrm2pp{std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN()},
                                           m_qrm1pp{std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN()}
    {
        // The integer n indexes a family of discrete Legendre polynomials indexed by k <= 2*n
    }

    Real norm_sq(int r)
    {
        Real prod = Real(2) / Real(2 * r + 1);
        for (int k = -r; k <= r; ++k) {
            prod *= Real(2 * m_n + 1 + k) / Real(2 * m_n);
        }
        return prod;
    }

    void initialize_recursion(Real x)
    {
        using std::abs;
        BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(abs(x) <= 1, "Three term recurrence is stable only for |x| <=1.");
        m_qrm2 = 1;
        m_qrm1 = x;
        // Derivatives:
        m_qrm2p = 0;
        m_qrm1p = 1;
        // Second derivatives:
        m_qrm2pp = 0;
        m_qrm1pp = 0;

        m_r = 2;
        m_x = x;
    }

    Real next()
    {
        Real N = 2 * m_n + 1;
        Real num = (m_r - 1) * (N * N - (m_r - 1) * (m_r - 1)) * m_qrm2;
        Real tmp = (2 * m_r - 1) * m_x * m_qrm1 - num / Real(4 * m_n * m_n);
        m_qrm2 = m_qrm1;
        m_qrm1 = tmp / m_r;
        ++m_r;
        return m_qrm1;
    }

    Real next_prime()
    {
        Real N = 2 * m_n + 1;
        Real s = (m_r - 1) * (N * N - (m_r - 1) * (m_r - 1)) / Real(4 * m_n * m_n);
        Real tmp1 = ((2 * m_r - 1) * m_x * m_qrm1 - s * m_qrm2) / m_r;
        Real tmp2 = ((2 * m_r - 1) * (m_qrm1 + m_x * m_qrm1p) - s * m_qrm2p) / m_r;
        m_qrm2 = m_qrm1;
        m_qrm1 = tmp1;
        m_qrm2p = m_qrm1p;
        m_qrm1p = tmp2;
        ++m_r;
        return m_qrm1p;
    }

    Real next_dbl_prime()
    {
        Real N = 2*m_n + 1;
        Real trm1 = 2*m_r - 1;
        Real s = (m_r - 1) * (N * N - (m_r - 1) * (m_r - 1)) / Real(4 * m_n * m_n);
        Real rqrpp = 2*trm1*m_qrm1p + trm1*m_x*m_qrm1pp - s*m_qrm2pp;
        Real tmp1 = ((2 * m_r - 1) * m_x * m_qrm1 - s * m_qrm2) / m_r;
        Real tmp2 = ((2 * m_r - 1) * (m_qrm1 + m_x * m_qrm1p) - s * m_qrm2p) / m_r;
        m_qrm2 = m_qrm1;
        m_qrm1 = tmp1;
        m_qrm2p = m_qrm1p;
        m_qrm1p = tmp2;
        m_qrm2pp = m_qrm1pp;
        m_qrm1pp = rqrpp/m_r;
        ++m_r;
        return m_qrm1pp;
    }

    Real operator()(Real x, size_t k)
    {
        BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(k <= 2 * m_n, "r <= 2n is required.");
        if (k == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (k == 1)
        {
            return x;
        }
        Real qrm2 = 1;
        Real qrm1 = x;
        Real N = 2 * m_n + 1;
        for (size_t r = 2; r <= k; ++r) {
            Real num = (r - 1) * (N * N - (r - 1) * (r - 1)) * qrm2;
            Real tmp = (2 * r - 1) * x * qrm1 - num / Real(4 * m_n * m_n);
            qrm2 = qrm1;
            qrm1 = tmp / r;
        }
        return qrm1;
    }

    Real prime(Real x, size_t k) {
        BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(k <= 2 * m_n, "r <= 2n is required.");
        if (k == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (k == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        Real qrm2 = 1;
        Real qrm1 = x;
        Real qrm2p = 0;
        Real qrm1p = 1;
        Real N = 2 * m_n + 1;
        for (size_t r = 2; r <= k; ++r) {
            Real s =
                (r - 1) * (N * N - (r - 1) * (r - 1)) / Real(4 * m_n * m_n);
            Real tmp1 = ((2 * r - 1) * x * qrm1 - s * qrm2) / r;
            Real tmp2 = ((2 * r - 1) * (qrm1 + x * qrm1p) - s * qrm2p) / r;
            qrm2 = qrm1;
            qrm1 = tmp1;
            qrm2p = qrm1p;
            qrm1p = tmp2;
        }
        return qrm1p;
    }

  private:
    size_t m_n;
    size_t m_r;
    Real m_x;
    Real m_qrm2;
    Real m_qrm1;
    Real m_qrm2p;
    Real m_qrm1p;
    Real m_qrm2pp;
    Real m_qrm1pp;
};

template <class Real>
std::vector<Real> interior_filter(size_t n, size_t p) {
    // We could make the filter length n, as f[0] = 0,
    // but that'd make the indexing awkward when applying the filter.
    std::vector<Real> f(n + 1, 0);
    auto dlp = discrete_legendre<Real>(n);
    std::vector<Real> coeffs(p+1, std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN());
    dlp.initialize_recursion(0);
    coeffs[1] = 1/dlp.norm_sq(1);
    for (size_t l = 3; l < p + 1; l += 2)
    {
        dlp.next_prime();
        coeffs[l] = dlp.next_prime()/ dlp.norm_sq(l);
    }

    for (size_t j = 1; j < f.size(); ++j)
    {
        Real arg = Real(j) / Real(n);
        dlp.initialize_recursion(arg);
        f[j] = coeffs[1]*arg;
        for (size_t l = 3; l <= p; l += 2)
        {
            dlp.next();
            f[j] += coeffs[l]*dlp.next();
        }
        f[j] /= (n * n);
    }
    return f;
}

template <class Real>
std::vector<Real> boundary_filter(size_t n, size_t p, int64_t s)
{
    std::vector<Real> f(2 * n + 1, 0);
    auto dlp = discrete_legendre<Real>(n);
    Real sn = Real(s) / Real(n);
    std::vector<Real> coeffs(p+1, std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN());
    dlp.initialize_recursion(sn);
    coeffs[0] = 0;
    coeffs[1] = 1/dlp.norm_sq(1);
    for (size_t l = 2; l < p + 1; ++l)
    {
        // Calculation of the norms is common to all filters,
        // so it seems like an obvious optimization target.
        // I tried this: The spent in computing the norms time is not negligible,
        // but still a small fraction of the total compute time.
        // Hence I'm not refactoring out these norm calculations.
        coeffs[l] = dlp.next_prime()/ dlp.norm_sq(l);
    }

    for (size_t k = 0; k < f.size(); ++k)
    {
        Real j = Real(k) - Real(n);
        f[k] = 0;
        Real arg = j/Real(n);
        dlp.initialize_recursion(arg);
        f[k] = coeffs[1]*arg;
        for (size_t l = 2; l <= p; ++l)
        {
            f[k] += coeffs[l]*dlp.next();
        }
        f[k] /= (n * n);
    }
    return f;
}

template <class Real>
std::vector<Real> acceleration_boundary_filter(size_t n, size_t p, int64_t s)
{
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(p <= 2*n, "Approximation order must be <= 2*n");
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(p > 2, "Approximation order must be > 2");
    std::vector<Real> f(2 * n + 1, 0);
    auto dlp = discrete_legendre<Real>(n);
    Real sn = Real(s) / Real(n);
    std::vector<Real> coeffs(p+2, std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN());
    dlp.initialize_recursion(sn);
    coeffs[0] = 0;
    coeffs[1] = 0;
    for (size_t l = 2; l < p + 2; ++l)
    {
        coeffs[l] = dlp.next_dbl_prime()/ dlp.norm_sq(l);
    }

    for (size_t k = 0; k < f.size(); ++k)
    {
        Real j = Real(k) - Real(n);
        f[k] = 0;
        Real arg = j/Real(n);
        dlp.initialize_recursion(arg);
        f[k] = coeffs[1]*arg;
        for (size_t l = 2; l <= p; ++l)
        {
            f[k] += coeffs[l]*dlp.next();
        }
        f[k] /= (n * n * n);
    }
    return f;
}


} // namespace detail

template <typename Real, size_t order = 1>
class discrete_lanczos_derivative {
public:
    discrete_lanczos_derivative(Real const & spacing,
                                size_t n = 18,
                                size_t approximation_order = 3)
        : m_dt{spacing}
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_integral_v<Real>, "Spacing must be a floating point type.");
        BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(spacing > 0, "Spacing between samples must be > 0.");

        if constexpr (order == 1)
        {
            BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(approximation_order <= 2 * n,
                             "The approximation order must be <= 2n");
            BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(approximation_order >= 2,
                             "The approximation order must be >= 2");
            m_f = detail::interior_filter<Real>(n, approximation_order);

            m_boundary_filters.resize(n);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                // s = i - n;
                int64_t s = static_cast<int64_t>(i) - static_cast<int64_t>(n);
                m_boundary_filters[i] = detail::boundary_filter<Real>(n, approximation_order, s);
            }
        }
        else if constexpr (order == 2)
        {
            auto f = detail::acceleration_boundary_filter<Real>(n, approximation_order, 0);
            m_f.resize(n+1);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m_f.size(); ++i)
            {
                m_f[i] = f[i+n];
            }
            m_boundary_filters.resize(n);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                int64_t s = static_cast<int64_t>(i) - static_cast<int64_t>(n);
                m_boundary_filters[i] = detail::acceleration_boundary_filter<Real>(n, approximation_order, s);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(false, "Derivatives of order 3 and higher are not implemented.");
        }
    }

    void reset_spacing(Real const & spacing)
    {
        BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(spacing > 0, "Spacing between samples must be > 0.");
        m_dt = spacing;
    }

    Real spacing() const
    {
        return m_dt;
    }

    template<class RandomAccessContainer>
    Real operator()(RandomAccessContainer const & v, size_t i) const
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename RandomAccessContainer::value_type, Real>,
                      "The type of the values in the vector provided does not match the type in the filters.");
        using std::size;
        BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(size(v) >= m_boundary_filters[0].size(),
            "Vector must be at least as long as the filter length");

        if constexpr (order==1)
        {
            if (i >= m_f.size() - 1 && i <= size(v) - m_f.size())
            {
                Real dv = 0;
                for (size_t j = 1; j < m_f.size(); ++j)
                {
                    dv += m_f[j] * (v[i + j] - v[i - j]);
                }
                return dv / m_dt;
            }

            // m_f.size() = N+1
            if (i < m_f.size() - 1)
            {
                auto &bf = m_boundary_filters[i];
                Real dv = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < bf.size(); ++j)
                {
                    dv += bf[j] * v[j];
                }
                return dv / m_dt;
            }

            if (i > size(v) - m_f.size() && i < size(v))
            {
                int k = size(v) - 1 - i;
                auto &bf = m_boundary_filters[k];
                Real dv = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < bf.size(); ++j)
                {
                    dv += bf[j] * v[size(v) - 1 - j];
                }
                return -dv / m_dt;
            }
        }
        else if constexpr (order==2)
        {
            if (i >= m_f.size() - 1 && i <= size(v) - m_f.size())
            {
                Real d2v = m_f[0]*v[i];
                for (size_t j = 1; j < m_f.size(); ++j)
                {
                    d2v += m_f[j] * (v[i + j] + v[i - j]);
                }
                return d2v / (m_dt*m_dt);
            }

            // m_f.size() = N+1
            if (i < m_f.size() - 1)
            {
                auto &bf = m_boundary_filters[i];
                Real d2v = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < bf.size(); ++j)
                {
                    d2v += bf[j] * v[j];
                }
                return d2v / (m_dt*m_dt);
            }

            if (i > size(v) - m_f.size() && i < size(v))
            {
                int k = size(v) - 1 - i;
                auto &bf = m_boundary_filters[k];
                Real d2v = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < bf.size(); ++j)
                {
                    d2v += bf[j] * v[size(v) - 1 - j];
                }
                return d2v / (m_dt*m_dt);
            }
        }

        // OOB access:
        BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(false, "Out of bounds access in Lanczos derivative");
        return std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN();
    }

    template<class RandomAccessContainer>
    RandomAccessContainer operator()(RandomAccessContainer const & v) const
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename RandomAccessContainer::value_type, Real>,
                      "The type of the values in the vector provided does not match the type in the filters.");
        using std::size;
        BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(size(v) >= m_boundary_filters[0].size(),
            "Vector must be at least as long as the filter length");

        RandomAccessContainer w(size(v));
        if constexpr (order==1)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m_f.size() - 1; ++i)
            {
                auto &bf = m_boundary_filters[i];
                Real dv = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < bf.size(); ++j)
                {
                    dv += bf[j] * v[j];
                }
                w[i] = dv / m_dt;
            }

            for(size_t i = m_f.size() - 1; i <= size(v) - m_f.size(); ++i)
            {
                Real dv = 0;
                for (size_t j = 1; j < m_f.size(); ++j)
                {
                    dv += m_f[j] * (v[i + j] - v[i - j]);
                }
                w[i] = dv / m_dt;
            }


            for(size_t i = size(v) - m_f.size() + 1; i < size(v); ++i)
            {
                int k = size(v) - 1 - i;
                auto &f = m_boundary_filters[k];
                Real dv = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < f.size(); ++j)
                {
                    dv += f[j] * v[size(v) - 1 - j];
                }
                w[i] = -dv / m_dt;
            }
        }
        else if constexpr (order==2)
        {
            // m_f.size() = N+1
            for (size_t i = 0; i < m_f.size() - 1; ++i)
            {
                auto &bf = m_boundary_filters[i];
                Real d2v = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < bf.size(); ++j)
                {
                    d2v += bf[j] * v[j];
                }
                w[i] = d2v / (m_dt*m_dt);
            }

            for (size_t i = m_f.size() - 1; i <= size(v) - m_f.size(); ++i)
            {
                Real d2v = m_f[0]*v[i];
                for (size_t j = 1; j < m_f.size(); ++j)
                {
                    d2v += m_f[j] * (v[i + j] + v[i - j]);
                }
                w[i] = d2v / (m_dt*m_dt);
            }


            for (size_t i = size(v) - m_f.size() + 1; i < size(v); ++i)
            {
                int k = size(v) - 1 - i;
                auto &bf = m_boundary_filters[k];
                Real d2v = 0;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < bf.size(); ++j)
                {
                    d2v += bf[j] * v[size(v) - 1 - j];
                }
                w[i] = d2v / (m_dt*m_dt);
            }
        }

        return w;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Real> m_f;
    std::vector<std::vector<Real>> m_boundary_filters;
    Real m_dt;
};

} // namespaces
#endif
```

Comment: The tests fail to compile with this code; did you accidentally link to the wrong version?

Comment: @TobySpeight: I received code review on github from the maintainers of boost.math, and failed to keep this question in sync with the resulting code changes. Fortunately, your comments were almost completely orthogonal to the comments made by the maintainers.

Comment: I have a question: was this code actually used in LIGO signal analysis which entered official LIGO publications? I am wandering whether one can cite LIGO analysis as an example of use of Lanczos(-like) derivatives.

Comment: No it was not used in LIGO signal analysis. I used the LIGO signal because the LIGO people made their data easily available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty dramatic demonstration image - there's no doubt that the function is worth having!

I make no claim to understand the mathematics, but I'll happily look over the C++ code.

---

I'll start with the includes, as we seem to be missing some that are required:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
```

We have a portability problem, as we've consistently omitted the namespace of `std::size_t` and `std::int64_t` (BTW, consider `std::int_fast64_t` as a better alternative to the latter, unless we need *exactly* 64 bits).

---

Now, let's move on to `class discrete_legendre`.

It's usually a bad idea to have a class that is constructed into an unusable state, requiring a second "initialization" phase before it's valid.  Sometimes it's unavoidable, but that's not the case here.  Simply pass the initialization parameters to the constructor, and omit the `initialize_recursion()` member (simply create a new instance, as that's no more work than resetting all the members).

```
    class discrete_legendre {
    public:
        discrete_legendre(std::size_t n, Real x)
            : m_n{n},
              m_r{2},
              m_x{x},
              m_qrm2{1},
              m_qrm1{x},
              m_qrm2p{0},
              m_qrm1p{1},
              m_qrm2pp{0},
              m_qrm1pp{0}
        {
            // The integer n indexes a family of discrete Legendre
            // polynomials indexed by k <= 2*n
        }
```

Here's an example of where we replace re-initialisation with re-construction:

```
template <class Real>
std::vector<Real> interior_filter(std::size_t n, std::size_t p) {
    // We could make the filter length n, as f[0] = 0,
    // but that'd make the indexing awkward when applying the filter.
    std::vector<Real> f(n + 1, 0);
    auto dlp = discrete_legendre<Real>(n, 0.0);
    std::vector<Real> coeffs(p+1, std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN());
    coeffs[1] = 1/dlp.norm_sq(1);
    for (std::size_t l = 3; l < p + 1; l += 2)
    {
        dlp.next_prime();
        coeffs[l] = dlp.next_prime()/ dlp.norm_sq(l);
    }

    for (std::size_t j = 1; j < f.size(); ++j)
    {
        Real arg = Real(j) / Real(n);
        dlp = {n, arg};
        f[j] = coeffs[1]*arg;
        for (std::size_t l = 3; l <= p; l += 2)
        {
            dlp.next();
            f[j] += coeffs[l]*dlp.next();
        }
        f[j] /= (n * n);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Minor issues: `norm_sq()` can be declared `const`.

---

The filter functions are next.

Please don't use `l` as a variable name; it looks too much like the digit `1`!

For indexing vectors, a good practice would be to use `std::vector<>::size_type` rather than assuming that it's `std::size_t`.  But don't get hung up on that.

All three filters have a common step, which should be factored out for maintainability:

> ```
> for (std::size_t j = 1; j < f.size(); ++j)
> {
>     Real arg = Real(j) / Real(n);
>     dlp = {n, arg};
>     f[j] = coeffs[1]*arg;
>     for (std::size_t l = 3; l <= p; l += 2)
>     {
>         dlp.next();
>         f[j] += coeffs[l]*dlp.next();
>     }
>     f[j] /= (n * n);
> }
> return f;
> ```

We could consider a Strategy pattern here, but I suspect that would lead to bigger and less clear code.

---

Leaving the `detail` namespace, we reach the main class, `discrete_lanczos_derivative`.

> ```
>    static_assert(!std::is_integral_v<Real>, "Spacing must be a floating point type.");
> ```

Why `!std::is_integral_v` rather than the more obvious `std::is_floating_point_v`?  Are we expecting this to work for `std::complex<>` values, perhaps?

Given that almost every method switches on `order`, I think that specializations or separate classes for first-order and second-order are likely to be clearer.  We could put the common parts in a base class.

> ```
>     BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(size(v) >= m_boundary_filters[0].size(),
>         "Vector must be at least as long as the filter length");
> ```

`v` is user-supplied, so an assert is the wrong kind of check here if it terminates the program.  I think it's better to throw a `std::out_of_range` or similar instead.

> ```
>     BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(false, "Out of bounds access in Lanczos derivative");
>     return std::numeric_limits<Real>::quiet_NaN();
> ```

Perhaps a signalling NaN would be more appropriate here?  Although, as I understand it, this seems to be reached only if we're instantiated for an out-of-range `order`.

> ```
> template<class RandomAccessContainer>
> RandomAccessContainer operator()(RandomAccessContainer const & v) const
> ```

This seems to be a duplicate of `operator()(RandomAccessContainer const & v, std::size_t i)`, with `i` set to `size(v)`.  So implement it by delegating:

```
template<class RandomAccessContainer>
RandomAccessContainer operator()(RandomAccessContainer const & v) const
{
    using std::size;
    return operator()(v, size(v));
}

template<class RandomAccessContainer>
Real operator()(RandomAccessContainer const & v,
                typename RandomAccessContainer::size_type i) const
```

There's not necessarily a performance penalty for this - the compiler may choose to inline it, or (better) arrange the functions so that one is a prefix of the other.

Comment: I have implemented basically every suggestion, except a couple: The variable `l` matches the notation in the reference; is that worth the readability? Maybe, maybe not, but it's consistent with how I've done other implementations. `std::is_integral_v` is used because multiprecision and interval arithmetic types don't pass `std::is_float_point_v`, and I still wanted to make sure that the imaging procssing guys don't use this unless they know what they're doing (I haven't tested any integer types; doubt it works.) All other mistakes have been fixed.

Comment: I know that you're not supposed to say thanks in the comments-which seems like reasonable guidance for other stack exchanges-but not for this one. That was a huge effort on your part which considerably improved my code. Thanks is absolutely in order.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of `!std::is_integral_v` against other choices - it may be worth adding a comment there so a future maintainer doesn't attempt to "correct" it (I haven't inspected the unit tests closely, but I expect such a change would break some).  As for the variable `l`, that's one of those general guidelines - you understand the reason for the advice, and then you can make a considered judgement whether it's clearer to match the reference or to rename the variable.  A judgement call, indeed.